# App for finding icons easily?

Tags: nautilus, launcher, icons

Occasionally I need to use a custom icon for something - a launcher created with alacarte, a custom .desktop file, or just a particular folder viewed in Nautilus.

I know there are LOADS of cool icons installed on my system at /usr/share/icons but browsing them is really awkward. Everything is scattered around, duplicated in different sizes (or symlinked to .svg) etc.

So, say I'm looking for a text file icon, or a purple folder or such, searching is a faff, and then when you do find results you need to work out what the best quality one is.

**Made me think that someone might have written an app for this?**

Comment: Why don't you use http://www.iconfinder.com/ ?

Comment: (while I do love that site,) Because I want to use an icon installed on my system. There are 14579 of them - no need to add others!

Comment: GPWM. I've voted to close this as a duplicate.